# Displaying list in R markdown without commas

Tags: r, markdown

I've been trying to display this list in R markdown without the commas in between items.

Here is the dataset:

```
print(reg.order)
[1] "North Pacific"   "Pacific"         "Western Pacific" "New England"    
[5] "Mid-Atlantic"    "South Atlantic"  "Gulf of Mexico"
```

And here is the code:

```
{r Paragraph_5, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
for (reg00 in 1:length(reg.order)){
  place <- reg.order[reg00]
  place[reg00] <- paste("**",place, "**", "\n\n", sep = "")
}
`r place`
```

This is what I keep getting:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share some example data from reg.order?

Comment: @PhDavey. Question has been edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
reg.order <- c("North Pacific","Pacific","Western Pacific","New England",
               "Mid-Atlantic","South Atlantic","Gulf of Mexico" )
place <- paste("**", reg.order, "**", collapse = "  \n")
```
`r place`
````

Resulting HTML render is:

```html
<p>
** North Pacific **<br />
** Pacific **<br />
** Western Pacific **<br />
** New England **<br />
** Mid-Atlantic **<br />
** South Atlantic **<br />
** Gulf of Mexico **
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

reg.order <- c("North Pacific", "Pacific", "Western Pacific", "New England", "Mid-Atlantic", "South Atlantic", "Gulf of Mexico")
```

```
{r Paragraph_5, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, ft.align = "left", results='asis'}
for (reg00 in 1:length(reg.order)){
  place <- paste0("**",reg.order[reg00],"**")
  cat(place)
  cat("\n\n")
}
```

As an aside, instead of print(reg00) for the sample data, post the output of dput(reg00) as it comes out in a format that is very easy to put straight into rstudio!